# Append row in pandas dataframe with values that were previously declared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there a way to save the columns and values you want to add before in a variable?
Like here:

```
var = "'r':0.1"
print(var)

dfnew = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df.values:
      dfnew = dfnew.append({val}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: needs more explanation, with desired input/output examples if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe is empty, as you just create it before entering the for loop, so `for i in df.values` does no iterations.

In order to do what you want, you could do:

```
var = {'r':0.1}
for i in range(len(var)):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=var.keys())
    vals = pd.Series(list(var.values())[0])
    new_df[list(var.keys())[0]] = new_df[list(var.keys())[0]]
                   .append(vals, ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)
    r
0  0.1
```

Comment: Excuse me I entered the wrong code that dataframe already exists. I have fixed it in my question.

Comment: Okay @Felix , see if this does what you want

Comment: If `var = {'r':0.1,'e':0.2}` comes out that `0  0.1  NaN`. What do you have to change?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to start a dataframe from a dictionary. It is not clear whether you want to add a new row/column or not. Please provide more information and maybe an example.

If I am right about transforming a dictionary into a data frame, check the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) page for examples.

Here is one example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```